Run-time error 9 when using Interior.ColorIndex on Cells object
I'm trying  to get back into VBA by doing some small exercises. In the following example, I can get all cells that meet the criteria to have a red font (commented out parts), but I can't get them to be filled red. It creates Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range. Why?
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Long

Columns(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
'Columns(1).Font.Color = 1

For i = 1 To Rows.Count

    If Cells(i, 1).Value < Range("E2").Value And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
    
        Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = vbRed
        'Cells(i, 1).Font.color = vbRed
        
    End If
    
Next i

End Sub


The issue is vbRed the color constants aren't the same as color indices. Try Interior.ColorIndex = 3 instead or Interior.Color = vbred

Colors in Excel VBA
The Docs

Subscript out of range (Error 9)


Elements of arrays and members of collections can only be accessed within their defined ranges.
... You referenced a nonexistent collection member...


Interior.ColorIndex Property


Returns or sets a Variant value that represents the color of the interior.
... The color is specified as an index value into the current color palette, or...


Interior.Color Property


Returns or sets the primary color of the object,...
... Use the RGB function to create a color value.


VBA Color Constants

vbRed is one of the 8 VBA color constants.



The Issue

You got the error because the ColorIndex property can only be an integer between 0 and 56, while the VBA color constant vbRed represents the number 255 which should be used with the Color property.

In the default color palette, the color index for the red color is 3 which you could use with the ColorIndex property.

Since the default color palette can be modified in Excel --> Options --> Save --> Preserve Visual Appearance of the Workbook... --> Colors, it is safer to use the Color property:
.Color = vbRed
.Color = 255 ' red
.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' red


To clear the color, you cannot use the Color property but you can use one of the following:
.ColorIndex = xlNone
.ColorIndex = 0


In VBA, vbRed is a so called enumeration. It is part of the VBA library and the VBA ColorConstants module. Therefore, you can also use it in the following ways:
.Color = VBA.vbRed
.Color = VBA.ColorConstants.vbRed




Colors & Code

The following code should help you familiarize yourself with what is what. Use it in a new workbook.


Sub ListStandardColors()
    
    Const COLOR_OFFSET As Long = 2
    
    Dim cell As Range: Set cell = Sheet1.Range("A1")
    cell.Value = "Index"
    cell.Offset(, 1).Value = "Value"
    cell.Offset(, 2).Value = "Color"
    
    Debug.Print vbLf & "Color Indices"
    Debug.Print "Odd Index", "Odd Color", "Even Index", "Even Color"
    Dim pint As Interior, i As Long
    For i = 1 To 56
        With cell.Offset(i)
            With .Offset(, COLOR_OFFSET).Interior
                .ColorIndex = i
                If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    Set pint = cell.Offset(i - 1, COLOR_OFFSET).Interior
                    Debug.Print pint.ColorIndex, pint.Color, _
                        .ColorIndex, .Color
                End If
            End With
            .Value = i
            .Offset(, 1).Value = .Offset(, COLOR_OFFSET).Interior.Color
        End With
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print vbLf & "VBA Color Constants"
    Debug.Print "Constant", "Color", "Index"
 
    Debug.Print "vbBlack", VBA.ColorConstants.vbBlack, 1
    Debug.Print "vbRed", VBA.vbRed, 3
    Debug.Print "vbGreen", vbGreen, 4
    Debug.Print "vbYellow", vbYellow, 6
    Debug.Print "vbBlue", vbBlue, 5
    Debug.Print "vbMagenta", vbMagenta, 7
    Debug.Print "vbCyan", vbCyan, 8
    Debug.Print "vbWhite", vbWhite, 2

End Sub

Results in the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G)
Color Indices
Odd Index     Odd Color     Even Index    Even Color
 1             0             2             16777215 
 3             255           4             65280 
 5             16711680      6             65535 
 7             16711935      8             16776960 
 9             128           10            32768 
 11            8388608       12            32896 
 13            8388736       14            8421376 
 15            12632256      16            8421504 
 17            16751001      18            6697881 
 19            13434879      20            16777164 
 21            6684774       22            8421631 
 23            13395456      24            16764108 
 25            8388608       26            16711935 
 27            65535         28            16776960 
 29            8388736       30            128 
 31            8421376       32            16711680 
 33            16763904      34            16777164 
 35            13434828      36            10092543 
 37            16764057      38            13408767 
 39            16751052      40            10079487 
 41            16737843      42            13421619 
 43            52377         44            52479 
 45            39423         46            26367 
 47            10053222      48            9868950 
 49            6697728       50            6723891 
 51            13056         52            13107 
 53            13209         54            6697881 
 55            10040115      56            3355443 

VBA Color Constants
Constant      Color         Index
vbBlack        0             1 
vbRed          255           3 
vbGreen        65280         4 
vbYellow       65535         6 
vbBlue         16711680      5 
vbMagenta      16711935      7 
vbCyan         16776960      8 
vbWhite        16777215      2 

